# Can I use PAM for authentication in my web application?

Tags: go, pam

I am writing a web application in Go, and was wondering if it was possible for me to use PAM to authenticate users as opposed to using a database to store user credentials. If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

PAM, by its very name, is a pluggable authentication module for Linux/Unix. Modules include local (e.g. /etc/passwd) or network-based (LDAP etc.) solutions.

It sounds like you want to delegate authentication/authorization to the *NIX system PAM system. You can certainly do this by binding to a cgo library that talks to the native PAM system.

But this may be a an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and connecting directly to the database may be easier. LDAP, for example has plenty of supported native Go packages: [gopkg.in/ldap.v2](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/ldap.v2)

Comment: I think this answer gets to the point. I also guessed that PAM is just a middle man.

Comment: Do I need to compile my go program as an .so to be compiled with PAM in mind?

Comment: it will be *FAR* easier for your web-app to talk to a DB than through the PAM system. Trust me. Unless there is a compelling reason to take advantage of PAM's Audit logging etc - I would *strongly* advise against this route.